# Сохранение Canvas в SVG

Tags: android, svg, android-canvas

Есть ли понятный алгоритм (или урок, или просто кусок кода) сохранения отрисованного в `Canvas` изображения в `SVG`?

Иными словами, нужно сохранить то, что приложение рисует при помощи инструментов `Canvas`, в вектор.

Comment: canvas - это растровое изображение

Comment: И как быть? Вот приложение рисует картинку при помощи всяких drawArc и drawLine. Как это сохранить в вектор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для преобразования Canvas в SVG используйте js библиотеку [canvas2svg.js.](https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg) [[Demo]](http://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/)

Ещё одна библиотека для преобразования: [html5-canvas-svg](https://code.google.com/archive/p/html5-canvas-svg/)

Ссылки на ресурсы взяты из ответа на аналогичный вопрос на enSO:
[**Method to convert HTML5 canvas to SVG?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069008/7394871)